# AWK: post-processing of the data based on two columns

Tags: csv, awk

I am dealing with the post-procession of CSV logs arranged in the multi-column format in the following order: the first column corresponds to the line number (ID), the second one contains its population (POP, the number of the samples fell into this ID) and the third column (dG) represent some inherent value of this ID (which is always negative):

```
ID, POP, dG
1, 7, -9.6000
2, 3, -8.7700
3, 6, -8.6200
4, 4, -8.2700
5, 6, -8.0800
6, 10, -8.0100
7, 9, -7.9700
8, 8, -7.8400
9, 16, -7.8100
10, 2, -7.7000
11, 1, -7.5600
12, 2, -7.5200
13, 9, -7.5100
14, 1, -7.5000
15, 2, -7.4200
16, 1, -7.3300
17, 1, -7.1700
18, 4, -7.1300
19, 3, -6.9200
20, 1, -6.9200
21, 2, -6.9100
22, 2, -6.8500
23, 10, -6.6900
24, 2, -6.6800
25, 1, -6.6600
26, 20, -6.6500
27, 1, -6.6500
28, 5, -6.5700
29, 3, -6.5500
30, 2, -6.4600
31, 2, -6.4500
32, 1, -6.3000
33, 7, -6.2900
34, 1, -6.2100
35, 1, -6.2000
36, 3, -6.1800
37, 1, -6.1700
38, 4, -6.1300
39, 1, -6.1000
40, 2, -6.0600
41, 3, -6.0600
42, 8, -6.0200
43, 2, -6.0100
44, 1, -6.0100
45, 1, -5.9800
46, 2, -5.9700
47, 1, -5.9300
48, 6, -5.8800
49, 4, -5.8300
50, 4, -5.8000
51, 2, -5.7800
52, 3, -5.7200
53, 1, -5.6600
54, 1, -5.6500
55, 4, -5.6400
56, 2, -5.6300
57, 1, -5.5700
58, 1, -5.5600
59, 1, -5.5200
60, 1, -5.5000
61, 3, -5.4200
62, 4, -5.3600
63, 1, -5.3100
64, 5, -5.2500
65, 5, -5.1600
66, 1, -5.1100
67, 1, -5.0300
68, 1, -4.9700
69, 1, -4.7700
70, 2, -4.6600
```

In order to reduce the number of the lines I filtered this CSV with the aim to search for the line with the highest number in the second column (POP), using the following AWK expression:

```
# search CSV for the line with the highest POP and save all lines before it, while keeping minimal number of the lines (3) in the case if this line is found at the beginning of CSV.
awk -v min_lines=3 -F ", " 'a < $2 {for(idx=0; idx < i; idx++) {print arr[idx]} print $0; a=int($2); i=0; printed=NR} a > $2 && NR > 1 {arr[i]=$0; i++}END{if(printed <= min_lines) {for(idx = 0; idx <= min_lines - printed; idx++){print arr[idx]}}}' input.csv > output.csv
```

thus obtaining the following reduced output CSV, which still has many lines since the search string (with highest POP) is located on 26th line:

```
ID, POP, dG
1, 7, -9.6000
2, 3, -8.7700
3, 6, -8.6200
4, 4, -8.2700
5, 6, -8.0800
6, 10, -8.0100
7, 9, -7.9700
8, 8, -7.8400
9, 16, -7.8100
10, 2, -7.7000
11, 1, -7.5600
12, 2, -7.5200
13, 9, -7.5100
14, 1, -7.5000
15, 2, -7.4200
16, 1, -7.3300
17, 1, -7.1700
18, 4, -7.1300
19, 3, -6.9200
20, 1, -6.9200
21, 2, -6.9100
22, 2, -6.8500
23, 10, -6.6900
24, 2, -6.6800
25, 1, -6.6600
26, 20, -6.6500
```

How it would be possible to further customize my filter via modifying my AWK expression (or pipe it to something else) in order to consider additionally only the lines with small difference in the negative value of the third column, dG  compared to the first line (which has the value most negative)? For example to consider only the lines different no more then 20% in terms of dG compared to the first line, while keeping all rest conditions the same:

```
  ID, POP, dG
    1, 7, -9.6000
    2, 3, -8.7700
    3, 6, -8.6200
    4, 4, -8.2700
    5, 6, -8.0800
    6, 10, -8.0100
    7, 9, -7.9700
    8, 8, -7.8400
    9, 16, -7.8100
    10, 2, -7.7000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both tasks can be done in a single `awk`:

```sh
awk -F ', ' 'NR==1 {next} FNR==NR {if (max < $2) {max=$2; n=FNR}; if (FNR==2) dg = $3 * .8; next} $3+0 == $3 && (FNR == n+1 || $3 > dg) {exit} 1' file file

ID, POP, dG
1, 7, -9.6000
2, 3, -8.7700
3, 6, -8.6200
4, 4, -8.2700
5, 6, -8.0800
6, 10, -8.0100
7, 9, -7.9700
8, 8, -7.8400
9, 16, -7.8100
10, 2, -7.7000
```

To make it more readable:

```sh
awk -F ', ' '
NR == 1 {
   next
}
FNR == NR {
   if (max < $2) {
      max = $2
       n = FNR
   }
   if (FNR == 2)
      dg = $3 * .8
   next
}
$3 + 0 == $3 && (FNR == n+1 || $3 > dg) {
   exit
}
1' file file
```

Comment: Actually, it produced nothing as the output: I just modified the output production according to the syntax of my old AWK expression that had worked perfectly .awk -F ", " 'NR==1 {next} FNR==NR {if (max < $2) {max=$2; n=FNR}; if (FNR==2) dg = $3 * .8; next} $3+0 == $3 && (FNR == n+1 || $3 > dg) {exit} 1' "proc.csv > filt.csv

Comment: https://awk.js.org/?gist=1763edf0c9af7248956603e98cdc97fc

Comment: @HotJAMS: You cannot test it from stdin because it needs to process file twice.

Comment: yes, now technically it works but the condition of the filtering is not exacrly what I was looking for. Actually the aim was always to seek for the line having the biggest number in the second column and then store it with several lines in new CSV. And then if there are still many linnes to apply the condition considering difference in the values of third column (dG), so to reducing the total number of the lines in the final output CSV...

Comment: If you want to keep max number logic in same command then I already have a working solution in answer with the generated output. That has been tested on gnu-awk and BSD awk

Comment: yep for that case it works well! but I need to customize it alitle bit for the case when the string is already located on the first three linnes and I don not need to consider additional lines (like theAWK expression shown in my first post). For example >>https://awk.js.org/?gist=6068c04091356ba2a8f2c6ce655ca128 with this CSV file your sollution still gives too many lines, while mine only three.

Comment: so the entire logic is to minimize the number of linnes while keeping inthe output the line with the maximum number in the second column (POP) +  few additional linnes based on the difference of the negative value (dG) of the third column! :-)